# Python C extension decorator

Tags: python, c, decorator, python-c-api

I apologize in advance for the long-winded background info.

I've been playing around with the Python/C-API recently (Python 3.4) and have gotten stumped.  My goal is to have a C extension which I can use as a function/method decorator.  I have a reasonably well working prototype for an LRU cache in the gist,   https://gist.github.com/pbrady/916495198910e7d7c713.  Although the cache works and is very fast, there are two issues problems :

1. The `type` returned by the my decorater is not function: i.e.

   ```
   >>> from lrucache import lrucache
   >>> @lrucache()
   ... def f(a, b):
   ...    return a+b
   ...
   >>> type(f)
   >>> <class 'lrucache.cache'>
   ```

   Because of this, the decorator does not work properly on methods - it seems that `self` gets lost because Python doesn't make an instance method when it sees my class (which makes sense).
2. Copying `__doc__` from the decorated function to my cache class doesn't impact the message displayed by `help`.

My idea to get around these issues was to simply return the user function with a few modifications rather than a new custom class object.  These modifications are

1. Add a `__wrapped__` attribute to the function and point it to the function.
2. Overwrite the `__call__` attribute so that function calls are directed to a custom C routine.

I was able to accomplish (1) but overriding a functions `__call__` method doesn't do anything since it's not generally used by the interpreter.

My Question (finally):
How do I create a Python function (i.e., a PyFunctionObject) which will call a C function?

Or, if there is a better way to do this, I would be interested in that as well.  This is largely a learning/fun exercise so I'm not too interested in Cython based solutions.

Comment: I haven't used the Python/C-API directly, but maybe (since it's a learning/fun exercise) try creating a decorator in python that calls the C functions. Or create a simple C decorator that returns the correct function value/type (depending on how ugly that is). Sorry don't know the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well your (2) step obviously fails because special attributes are looked up on the class, not on the instance:

```
In [1]: class Test:
   ...:     def __call__(self):
   ...:         print('Called class attribute!')
   ...:         

In [2]: t = Test()

In [3]: def new_call():
   ...:     print('Called instance attribute!')
   ...:     

In [4]: t.__call__ = new_call

In [5]: t()
Called class attribute!
```

And you don't want to modify the `function` class `__call__` method, since this would modify the semantics of the python code in a substantial way.

As far as I know there is *one* way to instantiate a `PyFunctionObject`, which is calling [`PyFunction_New`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/c-api/function.html?highlight=pyfunctionobject#c.PyFunction_New). The problem with it is that it requires a `PyCodeObject` as argument and to create such an object you can call:

- [`PyCode_NewEmpty`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/c-api/code.html?highlight=pycodeobject#c.PyCode_NewEmpty): creates an *invalid* code object. It is used *only* to create frame objects where you don't care of the code to put there.
- [`PyCode_New`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/c-api/code.html?highlight=pycodeobject#c.PyCode_New): creates a bytecode object. This is a beast with 14 arguments, one of which is a `PyObject *code` which should be a readable buffer that contains the binary representation of the bytecode.
- [`Py_CompileStringObject`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/c-api/veryhigh.html?highlight=compile#c.Py_CompileStringObject): this seems the only reasonable solution. Basically this is the `compile` built-in.

Once you have created the code object the creation of the function is trivial.
Note however that you wont gain *any* performance benefit doing this since the body of the function object is interpreted.

However there are other solutions to your problem:

- You could make your `lrucache` a [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3.4/howto/descriptor.html). This is what python does for methods to automatically pass `self` as first parameter, so you can emulate that behaviour.
- You could write a very very simple python module that imports your C extension and provides a function such as:

  ```
  from functools import wraps

  from _lrucache import cache

  def lrucache(func):
      cached_func = cache(func)

      @wraps(func)
      def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
          return cached_func(*args, **kwargs)

      return wrapper
  ```

  In this way you side-step the whole problem via python code.
- <s>You could create a subclass of the function type and return that object instead.
  However this might not work if python is checking for the exact type when building a class, and the implementation might not be trivial since the interpreter might assume some properties about function objects that you'd have to provide.</s> No, you can't subclass a function...

Comment: Thanks for the well thought out answer.  Sadly I don't have enough rep to upvote. The simple wrapper solution works pretty well.  I take about a 50% performance hit but it's still 4-5x faster than the pure python version.    I had tried subclassing function but ran into issues.  I thought this may be due to the function type not having Py_TPFLAGS_BASETYPE.  As far as the descriptor route goes, would this work for regular functions too or would I need a non-descriptor version as well?

Comment: @ptb Oh, I didn't check whether `function` was subclassable, so that route doesn't seem practical without serious hacks at the C level. Regarding the descriptor as far as the descriptor is concerned it should work. You'd have to implement a `__call__` method on `lrucache` that is called by normal functions, while the method lookups would first call `__get__` and use the `__call__` on the object returned there.

Comment: I was able to the descriptor version to work by adding a simple function in tp_descr_get.  Also, by using getset methods for __doc__ (as they do in descrobject.c) I was able to get the correct docstrings.  The finished version is at https://github.com/pbrady/fastcache.  Thanks for you help.